# Background does not load from external CSS in React build

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to load a background from an external CSS file into my React Project. It works fine on my local system. But once I upload it, the background simply vanishes and disappears into oblivion.

I'm using create-react-app and so far - while I encountered trouble with image loading before - I never had the external CSS die on me like this.

I already tried every solution I found but to no avail.

- Putting the background in public/img instead of src/img and using the %PUBLIC_URL%
- trying url(/img/bg.png) or url('/img/bg.png) or url('./img/bg.png)
- renaming folders

---

My folder structure is as follows:

```
 -- src
    |-- img
        '-- bg.png
    |-- App.js
    |-- App.css
```

My custom class for the background is:

```
.bg {
  background-image: url(./img/bg.png);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

My component uses two classes

```
<div className="App bg">Content</div>
```

The weird thing is, I've done a few other Apps where this was never an issue but I don't think I've done anything differently.

Comment: have you tried just `url(img/bg.png)` ?

Comment: @Pipe I tried that as well and it did not work. Just to be sure I tried it again and it's still not showing up

Comment: Did you try to access the image directly in the browser by writing the URL into the browser's address bar? Just to check if the image really is where you think it should be …?

Comment: I did that. If i follow the link indicated by the css file i reach the bg.png

Comment: Hmm. Checked with dev tools too? If you inspect the element in question, does dev tools say that the image is available? If so, your image is there, but the browser may refuse to show it for some reason. Maybe there are any other styles getting in your way? Something like "background: blah ...;"?

Comment: I checked it and it does appear there, and if I copy the direction I also find the file. So that can't be it